# Azure function binding multiple Service Bus events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a way to make an Azure function triggerable by multiple Service Bus event queues? For example, if there is a function which logic is valid for multiple cases(event start, event end- each inserted into a different Service Bus queue) and I want to reuse it for these events can I subscribe to both of them in the Service Bus from the same function?

I was looking for an answer to this question, but so far everywhere I checked it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions can be triggered by a single source queue or subscription.
If you'd like to consolidate multiple sources to serve as a trigger for a single function, you could forward messages to a single entity (let's assume a queue) and configure Function to be triggered by messages in that queue. Azure Service Bus support [Auto-Forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) natively.

Note that there cannot be more than 3 hops and you cannot necessarily know what the source was if message was forwarded from a queue. For subscriptions, there's a possible workaround to stamp messages.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on "For subscriptions, there's a possible workaround to stamp messages" please?

Comment: @John subscriptions have rules. Each rule has a filter and an action. An action can be used to "stamp" message headers. I.e. you can add additional metadata that a receiver can leverage. For example, if you have subscriptions and want to use a single Function to process both differently, each subscription could have a rule with action and would "stamp"/write a custom header with the subscription name. When the Function would receive a message, the code would be able to identify where that message is coming from. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to simply reuse code, what about refactoring that Function to create a class which is then used in multiple functions.

If your goal is implementing events aggregation, you could probably create an Azure Durable Function Workflow that would do a fan-in on multiple Events.

**Excerpt from https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/166:**

Processing Azure blobs in hourly batches.

1. New blob notifications are sent to a trigger function using Event Grid trigger.
2. The event grid trigger uses the singleton pattern to create a single orchestration instance of a well-known name and raises an event to the instance containing the blob payload(s).
3. To protect against race conditions in instance creation, the event grid trigger is configured as a singleton using SingletonAttribute.
4. Blob payloads are aggregated into a List and sent to another function for processing - in this case, aggregated into a single per-batch output blob.
5. A Durable Timer is used to determine the one-hour time boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider switching the pattern around by using only one queue but multiple Topics/Subscriptions for the clients.

Then the Function in question can be triggered by the Start-End Topic.

Some other Function can be triggered by the Working Topic, etc.

Comment: I see that when specifying the trigger in the azure function .json file I need to add subscription name and topic name. That means I can bind the trigger to only one topic, not multiple. Do you have any resources as reference?

Comment: Also, based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions it seems that topics are one-to-many: we can have many clients for one topic. But this is not what I was trying to achieve. In my example the relationship I wanted was many to one.

Comment: @yanis Well, no, what I'm saying is **use one Queue instead of many**, then configure a Topic for each Function.  So instead of trying to get a Function to trigger from different Queues, use the Topic to route all relevant messages on a single queue.